Why is this not a homotopy equivalence between $S^2$ w/ diameter and $S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^2 \vee S^2$?
By difference of their fundamental groups, it is obvious that $S^2$ w/ a diameter is not homotopy equivalent to $S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^2 \vee S^2$. However, I’m not sure what is wrong with my visualization below of deforming the former into the latter.
My idea was to deformation retract the diameter onto a point: to maintain continuity resulted in a corresponding deformation of the upper and lower hemispheres.
Since the open upper and lower hemispheres (i.e., without their boundary) is homeomorphic to $S^2$ (for example, see here), both of those lead to $S^2$ with a point in common. The equator similarly deforms into two copies of $S^1$ with a point in common.
I imagine that either this movement isn’t actually continuous, or that I’m visualizing the end product incorrectly (I think this is more likely the case). Alternatively, it might be that I’m visualizing this movement in some ambient space (for example, $R^3$). If this is the case, then what does this deformation yield?
But I’m not sure where I’m going wrong?


Your wedges got turned to smashes in the title.

@Randall corrected, thanks!

You can do the same argument to show that $S^1 \cong S^1 \vee S^1$.

Unfortunately \wedge doesn't give a wedge.

It looks like the green and red semicircles, which lie on the original sphere, somehow jumped off of the sphere before the final picture was reached. This looks like a very discontinuous move.
I suggest thinking about a balloon, with your two fingers on opposite poles of the balloon. Now, very carefully so that everything remains stable, push your two index fingers together until they touch. While this is going on, the diameter on the inside of the balloon that connects the tips of your two fingers shrinks down to a single point.

Thanks, that’s true. What should the end product look like then? I’m having trouble visualising it.

I added a brief description.

Thanks for the description. It definitely shows me that the horizontal circle at the equator with the diameter, is sent to a figure 8 shape. But I’m not sure how it maps the other parts of the sphere.

I get it now, it maps to a torus without a hole, I think?

That's one way to put it, yes.

I just wanted to drop a couple of drawings, to make clear how I try to visualize such spaces. Maybe this can be helpful for a next time: you have more examples of homotopies and homeomorphisms so you can double check the transformation you are thinking.
I am going to post a couple of different visualization for a space that is homotopic equivalent to the sphere with a string connecting two points.
First: you should not be afraid to interchange exterior and interior when you can. Here is an example of a homeomorphism which may not come to mind at first if you are too much tied into thinking of deforming $R^3$ instead of just the topological space.

You can image to take out the connecting string.
Now you can continuously contract it via a homotopy equivalence (it may not be obvious at first, try to convince yourself or use the theorem which states that quotienting out a contractible sub-complex is an h-equiv).

So what you actually get is a (closed and empty, hence kind of sad) croissant.
Another way to obtain such a visualization is the following, which is again an illustration of how "thinking in $R^3$" (or - in the general case - embedded in an $R^n$) may be confusing at first.
Imagine a torus, then think about "putting a disk" in one of its $2$ holes. These may seem different at first, because in one you are "closing" the hole where you can put the finger through (in $R^3$), the other is the "closed" (where you put the cream in a donut) hole.
Exactly as you can contract via a h-equiv a segment, you can contract (using the fact cited above) a disk via an h-equiv.
But! The two "clogged up" torus i described are actually homeomorphic via the homeomorphism $S^1\times S^1\stackrel{\text{swap}}{\longrightarrow} S^1\times S^1$ which swap the coordinates.
But now, the contraction gives

and the image on the bottom left is (homotopy equivalent to) $S^2\cup \text{string}$.

Thanks for this, the second example is really interesting! I also appreciate your general thoughts on problems of this sort.
For your first example, aren’t we thinking in some ambient space throughout, for example, when we “move the string out”? The outside isn’t part of the space to begins with.
